# Chaining multiple class arguments(tried many ways)

Tags: python, oop

How should I initialize multiple class arguments that came as chain and then calculate sum of them?

I've tried many ways but NOTHING

Do you have any idea?

```
>>> Chain(2.5)(2)(2)(2.5) # sum
9

>>> Chain(3)(1.5)(2)(3) # sum
9.5
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is this `Chain` class that you are using?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show your code.

Comment: Please update your question with these `"tried many ways"`.

Comment: I wouldn't write code like this in the first place. Just accept arbitrary arguments and iterate over them inside the callable.

Comment: Chain is a class that I have to complete it to calculate sum of the argumets

Comment: You can do something make `Chain` a class with a `__call__` method, so that calling an instance always produces another `Chain` instance. But then you need to additional method to convert the "final" instance to an `int`, like `Chain(2.5)(2)(2)(2.5).result()`.

Comment: If all you want to do is take the sum of things then why not simply write `sum([2.5, 2, 2, 2.5])`? What's wrong with that?

Comment: It's a question that I saw in the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you'll want to add a `__call__` method to your class so that calling an instance returns a *new* instance. Your class should also subclass the type matching the result you want.

In this specific case, the new instance could, for example, maintain a running sum of the initial value and all successive arguments.

```
class Chain(float):
    def __call__(self, x):
        return Chain(self + x)
```

Then

```
>>> Chain(2.5)
2.5
>>> Chain(2.5)(2)
4.5
>>> Chain(2.5)(2)(2)
6.5
>>> Chain(2.5)(2)(2)(2.5)
9.0
```